# Diferença entre tabela relacional e registro em linha

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Tenho uma estrutura de empresas e categorias organizadas em 3 tabelas:

- `empresa` -> Registro de todas as empresas cadastradas.
- `categoria` -> Registro de todas as categorias cadastradas.
- `rel_categoria`-> Relação entre `empresa` e `categorias`.

Onde eu armazeno o dado da seguinte maneira na tabela `rel_categoria`:

```
id (primary_key) | id_empresa | id_categoria
```

E quando preciso obter as categorias de uma empresa, faço a seleção relacionada. Até ai tudo ok.

Mas me surgiu a seguinte dúvida: Por que utilizar uma tabela extra para salvar esses registros sendo que eu posso armazenar os mesmos em uma coluna na tabela `empresa`?

Exemplo na tabela `empresa`:

```
id | nome_empresa |  categorias  | [..etc..]
 1 | 'Lojinha'    | 1, 7, 14, 16 | ...
```

A única razão que me vem em mente seria no caso de efetuar uma contagem. Ex.: Quantas empresas usam a categoria `X`?

Existe algum outro motivo? Alguma questão estrutural? De performance? Etc.. Faço o gerenciamento do banco através do `MySql` e `PHP`.

Comment: Posso estar falando bobagem mas em frameworks de ORM como o Hibernate para o Java e o Eloquent para PHP, utilizam esse padrão. Creio  que seja mais fácil para retornar por exemplo a categoria(objeto) de uma empresa.

Comment: @Rafael quando você diz 'esse padrão', se refere ao padrão de tabela relacionada?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A estrutura que você montou, com tabelas empresas e categorias e uma terceira tabela de relacionamento obedece os conceitos utilizados em **banco de dados relacional**.

Daí podemos partir para questões como **modelagem**, **normalização**, **formas normais**, etc...

Partindo do pressuposto que **uma EMPRESA pode ter várias CATEGORIAS**, e **uma CATEGORIA pode estar presente em várias EMPRESAS**, temos um **relacionamento N:N** que é representado no banco usando esta **tabela de relacionamento**.

Isso também **impacta na performance**. Pois se você monta a estrutura normalizada, com chaves primárias e estrangeiras, índices e afins, as **consultas são otimizadas**.

Imagine se você armazenar todas as categorias de uma empresa em uma **coluna do tipo varchar**, a **performance da consulta vai cair**, pois você precisará utilizar **funções para tratamento de string** para localização das informações desejadas, entre outras coisas.

Comment: De fato eu faço tratamento de strings quebrando nas virgulas, montando arrays, etc.. É um tipo de estrutura que eu vi muito mas com pouco "por que" de se fazer assim. Mas assim mais claro, obrigado.

Comment: Realmente, algumas vezes a gente vai fazendo as coisas e como vai dando certo não nos preocupamos com a teoria, mas precisamos entender os conceitos e o por quê das coisas. Assim podemos tomar melhores decisões ao implementar nossas soluções.

Answer (score 2):

Você já respondeu.

Embora também dê para fazer a contagem ou outros tipos de busca se fizer uma coluna com as categorias dela. Se compensará depende muito do que pretende fazer. Quase sempre dá para fazer bem com a coluna multi-valorada. É mais complicado acessar os dados das categorias neste formato. Nada exagerado, mas alguém pode olhar pra sua *query* e não entender de cara o que aquilo faz. Tem mais chance de cometer um erro.

Só precisa de uma tabela extra mesmo quando for acessar categorias sem nenhum vínculo com a empresa. É raro precisar disto. Mas em outras situações isto pode não sr tão verdade. Até dá para fazer sem a tabela extra, mas pode ficar bem lento ter que olhar todas empresas para descobrir o que deseja, mas duvido que isto corra na maioria das situações, principalmente neste caso específico relatado.

Por outro lado criar uma tabela extra vai quase sempre exigir um `JOIN` que costuma ser uma operação cara e é bom evitar se der para fazer isto decentemente.

Se você estiver algum software que exija de um jeito ou de outro, aí tem que seguir o que mandam, ou tentar abandonar esse requisito.

Normalmente eu iria de coluna sem tabela extra, pelo menos até ter um indicativo que isto seria ruim, mas não sei seu caso específico.

O pessoal prega muito a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) sem analisar o caso real. Uma coisa é normalizar o que precisa ser normalizado, o que faz sentido para aquele modelo, outra é forçar normalização onde não precisa só porque a pessoa aprendeu que normalizar é sempre bom.